# com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.example.myapplication.Orders

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I have checked the other questions. None of them solves my problem. I want to retrieve data from the Firebase Realtime Database's node **"orderDetails"** and show them in the RecyclerView

**UserActivity.java**

```
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    RecyclerView ordersList;
    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_user);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        String pickerUID = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        try {
            DatabaseReference mDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            databaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Pickers").child(pickerUID).child("orderDetails");
            databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

            ordersList = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
            ordersList.setHasFixedSize(false);
            ordersList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Orders,OrdersViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Orders, OrdersViewHolder>
                (Orders.class, R.layout.orders_list, OrdersViewHolder.class, databaseReference) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrdersViewHolder ordersViewHolder, Orders orders, int i) {

                try {
                    ordersViewHolder.setUserName(orders.getUserName());
                    ordersViewHolder.setUserAddress(orders.getUserAddress());
                    ordersViewHolder.setUserEmail(orders.getUserEmail());
                    ordersViewHolder.setDate(orders.getDate());
                    ordersViewHolder.setTime(orders.getTime());
                    ordersViewHolder.setUserUID(orders.getUserUID());
                    ordersViewHolder.setUserPhoneNumber(orders.getPhoneNumber());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(UserActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        };
        ordersList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }

    public static class OrdersViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        View view;
        public TextView userUIDTV;

        public OrdersViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view=itemView;
        }

        public void setUserName(String userName) {
            TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.userName);
            name.setText(userName);
        }
        public void setUserAddress(String userAddress) {
            TextView address = view.findViewById(R.id.userAddress);
            address.setText(userAddress);
        }
        public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
            TextView email = view.findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
            email.setText(userEmail);
        }
        public void setDate(String date) {
            TextView userDate = view.findViewById(R.id.date);
            userDate.setText(date);
        }
        public void setTime(String time) {
            TextView userTime = view.findViewById(R.id.time);
            userTime.setText(time);
        }
        public void setUserUID(String userUID) {
            userUIDTV = view.findViewById(R.id.userUID);
            userUIDTV.setText(userUID);

        }
        public void setUserPhoneNumber(String userPhoneNumber) {
            TextView phoneNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.userPhoneNumber);
            phoneNumber.setText(userPhoneNumber);
        }

    }
}
```

**Orders.java**

```
public class Orders {

  private String userName;
  private String userAddress;
  private String userEmail;
  private String date;
  private String time;
  private String userUID;
  private String phoneNumber;

    public Orders(String userName, String userAddress, String userEmail, String date, String time, String phoneNumber, String userUID) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.userAddress = userAddress;
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
        this.userUID = userUID;
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getUserAddress() {
        return userAddress;
    }

    public void setUserAddress(String userAddress) {
        this.userAddress = userAddress;
    }

    public String getUserEmail() {
        return userEmail;
    }

    public void setUserEmail(String userEmail) {
        this.userEmail = userEmail;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setUserPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getUserUID() {
        return userUID;
    }

    public void setUserUID(String userUID) {
        this.userUID = userUID;
    }

    public Orders() {

    }
}
```

**My Database**
https://ibb.co/DCHfBDt

**I want to get the data from the node "orderDetails"**

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you post the log

Answer (score 0):

Change your database structure and add a random id under `orderDetails`:

```
orderDetails
    randomId
        date : date_value
        phoneNumber : phoneNo_value
```

Now, when you do:

```
databaseReference = mDatabaseReference.child("Pickers").child(pickerUID).child("orderDetails");
```

it will retrieve the data of type `Orders`

Comment: I did not get it. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: when adding data to the database, just add a randomid after `orderDetails`..

Comment: you are retrieving an object of type `orders`.. if you add a randomid then you will be able to retrieve that object. Right now you are retrieving everything as String.. You are retrieving `date` as String with a `randomid`, you will retrieve date as a field in class `Orders`

Comment: like this?  => `databaseReference = DatabaseReference.child("Pickers").child(pickerUID).child("orderDetails/").child("reigiugieufre");`?

Comment: like this `databaseReference = DatabaseReference.child("Pickers").child(pickerUID).child("orderDetails").push();`

Comment: where is it showing that? Are you getting any error now?

Comment: In the log. The error is - "Directory does not exist"

Comment: which Directory

Comment: The Firebase Directory from where it has to retrieve data